# Fill only fields that are defined at Interface

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I am building a shopping cart service that uses a method to add a passed JSON object to a cart object. But only the defined fields in the interface IProduct should be filled.

JSON Object

```
{
    "title": "Title 1",
    "descriptionHtml": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore.",
    "vendor": "1",
    "variants": [
        {
            "id": "aaaa",
            "price": "12.95",
            "quantity": "1"
        }
    ],
    "images": [
        {
            "transformedSrc": "https://path/to/image"
        }
    ],
    "filters": [
        "Pizza"
    ],
    "ratings": "1321"
}
```

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

export interface IProduct {
    title: string;
    descriptionHtml: string;
    vendor: string;
    variants?: (VariantsEntity)[] | null;
    images?: (ImagesEntity)[] | null;
}

export interface VariantsEntity {
    id: string;
    price: string;
    quantity: string;
}

export interface ImagesEntity {
    transformedSrc: string;
}

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})

export class CartService
{
    cart: IProduct[] = [];

    constructor() { }

    setProduct(product)
    {
        this.cart.push(product);
    }
}
```

Using `this.cart.push(product)` pushes the whole JSON object.
But i don't need fields like "filters", "ratings".

Is there a possibility with Typescript that only the actual interface fields are created?

**EDIT: What possibilities do i have here?**

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a possibility with Typescript that only the actual interface fields are created

You are looking for `Exact Types`. They are not supported natively at the moment.

## Further Discussion

- Follow the thread on TypeScript GitHub: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936

Comment: Thanks for the Thread Link. Hopefully  this will be possible with Typescript

Answer (score 0):

Found a Solution that works for me with Spread Operator

```
const {ratings, filters, ...filteredProduct} = product;
this.cart.push(filteredProduct);
```